# I want to ignore strong from the html tag which contain spaces in php

Tags: php

For example if i have a array in the below format

```
<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></div>

<div><strong>Ravjaja</strong></div>

<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>

<div><strong>yuaiiaiia</strong></div>

<div></div>
```

i want to ignore   from the spaces which means my array should become like this after removing the

```
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>

<div><strong>Ravjaja</strong></div>

<div>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

<div><strong>yuaiiaiia</strong></div>

<div></div>

<div></div>
```

is there any possible way i thought to split and replace using the array functions in php 
i tried in this way

$keywords = preg_split("`<div>`", $lval);
      print_r($keywords);
and thought to extract each tag and remove the strong but i was unable to do in that way

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0):

```
$elements = array(
    '<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>Ravjaja</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>yuaiiaiia</strong></div>',
    '<div></div>'
);

foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    if (strpos('&nbsp', $element) !== FALSE) {
        $elements[$key] = str_replace('<strong>', '', $element);
        $elements[$key] = str_replace('</strong>', '', $element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i still need a refinement what if the array('<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>Ravjaja</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>',
    '<div><strong>yuaiiaiia</strong></div>',
    '<div></div>') which i gave is already a value in an array
is there a way for that

Comment: split it by </div><div>

Comment: didnt get that can u please elaborate

Comment: explode('<div></div>', $htmlString) will spit your string ibto array and you can use my solution then

Comment: used the way u told me but i dont think it is working because i find that the control is not going into if loop, if i m not correct can u check once

Answer (score 0):

only possible way should be like this

```
   $my_array=str_replace("<div><strong>&nbsp;","<div>",$my_array);
   $my_array=str_replace("&nbsp;</strong>","",$my_array);
```